# Delphi custom enumerator gives strange errors

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, enumerator

When creating a custom enumerator for string parsing I see some strange error messages. When using record It gives the following error:

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'TSplitStringEnumerator' and 'Pointer'

When using classes (insert a few .Create calls in the code) instead of records I get some Internal Errors from time to time:

Does anyone know how to keep the enumeration work with record data types instead of classes?

```
type
    TSplitStringEnumerator = record
        StringToParse:          string;
        Separator:              Char;
        S:                      Integer;
        E:                      Integer;
        L:                      Integer;
        function    GetCurrent  (): string; inline;
        function    MoveNext    (): Boolean; inline;
        property    Current:    string read GetCurrent;
    end;

    TSplitStringGenerator = record
        Enum:                   TSplitStringEnumerator;
        function GetEnumerator: TSplitStringEnumerator; inline;
    end;

function SplitString( const StringToParse: string; Separator: Char ): TSplitStringGenerator; //inline;
begin
    Result.Enum.StringToParse := StringToParse;
    Result.Enum.Separator     := Separator;
    Result.Enum.S             := 0;
    Result.Enum.E             := 0;
    Result.Enum.L             := Length( StringToParse );
end;

procedure Test();
var
    S: string;
begin
    for S in SplitString( 'A;B;C', ';' ) do begin
        OutputDebugString( PChar( S ) );
    end;
end;

{ TSplitStringGenerator }

function TSplitStringGenerator.GetEnumerator(): TSplitStringEnumerator;
begin
    Result := Enum;
end;

{ TSplitStringEnumerator }

function TSplitStringEnumerator.GetCurrent(): string;
begin
    Result := Copy( StringToParse, S, E - S );
end;

function TSplitStringEnumerator.MoveNext(): Boolean;
begin
    S := E + 1;
    Result := S <= L;
    E := S;
    while ( E <= L ) and ( StringToParse[ E ] <> Separator ) do Inc( E );
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the similar [bug report #72213](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=72213) on QC. The bug was fixed in Delphi 2010 (see resolution comments).

Comment: +1 that looks pretty likely to be the explanation because OP is using a managed type

Comment: Yep, replacing the string with a PChar effectively removes the compilation error in D2009.

Comment: In order to make it work without moving to D2010 I think you'll have to switch to a class. With a record, if you can't use a managed type then there's no way to avoid a leak.

Comment: I can see from the description of the QC bug that this is the case. Thank you for pointing out this QC ticket, I did not find it before.

Answer (score 2):

That code compiles and appears to run successfully for me in Delphi 2010. The output is:

```
Debug Output: A Process Project4.exe (4656)
Debug Output: B Process Project4.exe (4656)
Debug Output: C Process Project4.exe (4656)
```

Is it possible that enumerators with records are not supported in Delphi 2007?

Comment: It is quite possible. The code does not compile in D2009 and D2009 definitely supports enumerators. Also, when you code out the for in loop yourself (while `x.GetEnumerator.MoveNext` do something with `x.GetEnumerator.Current`) it actually does compile, although it then gets stuck in an endless loop. Haven't gotten around to determining whether that is the code in Ritsaert's example or the compiler making a mess of it. On the other hand: the D2009 help clearly indicates using records is supported.

Comment: The endless loop is caused by the GetEnumerator function returning a new - freshly initialised version of its Enum member everytime you call it?! I thought `Result := RecordMember` does a copy of the stuff in RecordMember to the Result? And it does, when I change the `x.GetEnumerator.Whatever` to `x.Enum.Whatever`...